# How to handle Compressed Request in WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, iis-7, .net-4.5, gzipstream, ihttpmodule

We have a WCF REST service hosted on IIS 7 with .NET Framework 4.5. The client is sending data in GZip compressed format with request headers:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type: application/xml
```

But we are getting bad request from the server, if the request is in compressed format. We enabled Request compression by implementation of IHttpModule that will filter/modify incoming requests. From my understanding, this is failing because WCF uses original content length (that of compressed data) instead of Decompressed data. So here are my questions:

Is there any way we can fix this content length issues in IIS7/.NET 4.5? My HTTP module implementation is given below:

```
httpApplication.Request.Filter = New GZipStream(httpApplication.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress)`
```

If fixing the content length issue is not possible at server side, is there any way I can send original content length from client with a compressed request? Client side implementation is as follows:

```
using (Stream requeststream = serviceRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
   if (useCompression)
   {
       using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(requeststream, CompressionMode.Compress))
       {
           zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           zipStream.Close();
           requeststream.Close();
       }

       serviceRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
   }
   else
   {
       requeststream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       requeststream.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with our server giving a '400 bad request' when I send a compressed request. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can work for you **Compression and the Binary Encoder**
[MSDN: Choosing a Message Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx)